# How to send as gift with Expresso Store

Tags: expresso-store

How can I send an order as gift in Expresso Store? I tried the [Gift Wrapping add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/store-gift-wrapping) but I'm not sure how to make it work.

Appreciate your help in achieving the above. Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question to be a bit more specific about what you are trying to achieve? (e.g. what you have put in the answer comments below). As it is this question is very vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe all you need for the basics of a gift order is the ability to have different billing and shipping addresses, which Expresso Store allows. So gifts can be done, you'd just want a custom field to capture 'Is this a Gift?' option.

The add-on, [Gift Wrapping](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/store-gift-wrapping), that you mentioned above, seems as if it's more to provide an option, like, well… 'gift wrapping'. I mean, if you were going to charge, like Amazon and other stores do to have the item wrapped and a card added to it, rather than just shipping it to the person.

If you're not offering, gift wrapping— meaning you won't offer to wrap and add a card to a gift item, then I believe you can just add one or more custom fields related to how to handle a gift, such as 'Is this a gift?' and/or 'Include Receipt?'

Comment: thanks for the pointers, I happened to think the Gift Wrapping add-on will automate the whole gifting process. But we are selling both print and downloadable magazines that can be gifted. Like a member can gift a year's digital subscription which can be only downloaded from the members section. Whereas the receiver is not a member yet, so wondering how to get them to join and redeem their gift.

Comment: I don't know the full functionality of the Gift Wrapping add-on, but from its description, that doesn't sound like it would do that. For gifting 'Digital' it sounds like you need to set-up a reclaim process. Let me think about that.

Comment: My initial thoughts for setting up a redeem system. Since it's digital, you'll need to collect the gift recipients `email_address`. You'll definitely want the 'Is this a Gift?' custom field. You'd need to send that person an email, after the order was completed. The email could contain a redeem code that they enter during the registration process. Redeem code with registered email can verify, then move them to proper membership group. If you wanted automation, have email send link to specific registration form, which verifies redeem code, places in proper group.

Comment: After much research, the above work flow helped in setting up a gift option, thnx!